# Font Installs, But Not in FontBook

Tags: macos, font-book

I've tried to install two TTF fonts, but they don't show up in FontBook.

Message in Console is:

`Sandbox: FontValidator(897) deny(1) file-read-metadata /`

Answer (score 2):

The files were already present in `~/Library/Fonts` but they had different permissions than the other files. By changing permissions -- using `sudo chmod 755 blah.ttf` -- and then running FontBook, everything worked.